# how can i get the index of active class with only javascript

Tags: javascript, activerecord

I am trying to get the index of the current active element with the javascript function .

my html is

```
<input type="text" name="check" class="check"/>
<textarea id="check" class="check"></textarea>
```

and i have tried like this

```
var focused = document.activeElement;
// I want to insert the index in this to get the selected class
var txtarea = document.getElementsByClassName("check")[1];
```

also i have tried to get the index like this

```
focused.index  && focused.getIndex
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this with the use `indexOf(focused)`

```
var focused = document.activeElement;  
    var nodeList = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.getElementsByClassName('check')); 
    var txtarea = document.getElementsByClassName("check")[nodeList.indexOf(focused)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
window.onload=function() {
  var checks = document.getElementsByClassName("check");
  for (var i=0;i<checks.length;i++) {
    check[i].onfocus=function() {this.className+=" active";)
    check[i].onblur=function() {this.className.replace(" active","");
  }
}
```

then you can get it using

```
document.querySelector(".active");
```

If you want to know the index of the active check:

```
window.onload=function() {
  var checks = document.getElementsByClassName("check");
  for (var i=0;i<checks.length;i++) {
    check[i].setAttribute("data-idx")=i;
    check[i].onfocus=function() {this.className+=" active";)
    check[i].onblur=function() {this.className.replace(" active","");
  }
}
```

and

```
document.querySelector(".active").getAttribute("data-idx");
```